# jquery/javascript file validation 2 strings compration (file extansions) fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm building a from validator file and I have a problem with comparing the extensions from some reason , what I'm trying to do is define in the HTML by data attribute call data-extntions the extansions that allowed to use in the current file input, this is the code I'm running:

```
case "file" : 
  var allowed_files_extansions = $(this).data("extensions")
  var is_valid = Validator.is_file(current_value , allowed_files_extansions);
  if(!is_valid){
     Validator.errors_handler(Validator.invalid_text , field_human_name , $(this));
     is_submit = false;
     return false;
  }else{
    is_submit = true;
  }
  break;

is_file : function(file_value , allowed_files_extansions){
  file_extension = file_value.split('.').pop();
  allowed_files_extansions = allowed_files_extansions.split(',');
  for(i=0;i<allowed_files_extansions.length;i++){
     if(file_extension == allowed_files_extansions[i]){
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<input class="form-control deal" data-extensions=" jpg , png , gif , JPG "  id="image_file" data-title="file" data-validate="file" type="file" name="userfile"  />
```

when I upload a file and console.log the `var file_extension` and the `var allowed_files_extansions[i]` I get the exact same string and the type of both of them is string too and it's still doesn't get inside the if statement.

Can someone help me with that please? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you have whitespaces in your data-extension attribute.

Change

```
data-extensions=" jpg , png , gif , JPG "
```

to

```
data-extensions="jpg,png,gif,JPG"
```

or use [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2FTrim) on `allowed_files_extansions[i]`

Furthermore.. it seems that you are trying to reinvent the wheel.
Take a look at the [`accept`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) attribute for `input[type=file]`
e.g.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png" />
```

Comment: thank you vary much mate. about the accept attribute - i want it to be suppurted in ie8 at least